# React build looks different than React dev

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I just finished the dev of my react app and ran
`npm run build` to get my production version.

Everything works but some CSS styling...

Everything just looks perfect in my dev version but for some reason it doesn't in my build version.

Here are the problems :

My popup in dev :

[image: Popup in dev mode]

My popup in build :

[image: Popup in build mode]

Here's the code for my popup :

```
import styles from "./DeletePopUp.module.css";
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { deletePopUpContext } from "./../../../contexts/shared/deletePopUpContext";
import notificationContext from "../../../contexts/notificationContext";
import authContext from "../../../contexts/authContext";

import { ReactComponent as Close } from "./close.svg";

import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import api from "./../../../services/api";

const DeletePopUp = () => {
  const { setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(authContext);
  const { deletePopUp, setDeletePopUp } = useContext(deletePopUpContext);
  const { setNotification } = useContext(notificationContext);
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(false);
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    if (value === deletePopUp.textToEnter) {
      setCorrect(true);
    } else {
      setCorrect(false);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    if (correct) {
      api.delete(deletePopUp.link).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.ok) {
          if (deletePopUp.toDelete === "asso") {
            Cookies.set("hasAssociation", false);
            Cookies.remove("association_id");
            Cookies.remove("association_uuid");
            setNotification({
              type: "success",
              state: "isShown",
              mesage: "Votre association a bien été supprimé",
            });
          }

          if (deletePopUp.toDelete === "user") {
            Cookies.remove("x-access-token");
            Cookies.remove("x-refresh-token");
            Cookies.remove("authenticated");
            Cookies.remove("hasAssociation");
            Cookies.remove("association_id");
            Cookies.remove("association_uuid");
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
            setNotification({
              type: "success",
              state: "isShown",
              mesage: "Votre compte a bien été supprimé",
            });
          }
          setDeletePopUp({});

          history.push("/");
        }
      });
    }
  };

  if (deletePopUp.isShown) {
    return (
      <div
        className={`${styles.popup} ${
          deletePopUp.isShown === false ? styles.vanishPopup : ""
        } ${deletePopUp.isShown === true ? styles.activePopup : ""}`}
      >
        <Close className={styles.close} onClick={() => setDeletePopUp({})} />
        <div>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>{deletePopUp.title}</h1>
          <p>{deletePopUp.text}</p>
          <input
            className="secondary-input"
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
            placeholder={deletePopUp.textToEnter}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          className={`${
            correct ? "red-outlined-button" : "disabled-outlined-button"
          } ${styles.btn}`}
          onClick={correct ? handleDelete : null}
          disabled={correct ? false : true}
        >
          {deletePopUp.buttonText}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
};

export default DeletePopUp;
```

And the CSS that is not working :

```
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white !important;
  width: clamp(200px, 75%, 750px);
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 200;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding: 50px;
}

.activePopup {
  animation: showPopUp 0.5s ease-in-out forwards !important;
}

.vanishPopup {
  animation: hidePopUp 0.5s ease-in-out backwards !important;
}

@keyframes showPopUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
  }

  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10000px 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

@keyframes hidePopUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
  }
}
```

My footer in dev :

[image: Footer in dev mode]

My footer in build :

[image: Footer in build mode]

I tried to prioritize some CSS properties by adding `!important` on them but it doesn't work.

Here's the code for my footer :

```
import styles from "./Footer.module.css";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactComponent as Shape } from "./footer.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Web } from "./Web.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Facebook } from "./Facebook.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Instagram } from "./Instagram.svg";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.footerContainer}>
      <Shape className={styles.shape} />
      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <div>
          <div className={styles.logo}>
            Anima<span>Z</span>one
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/adopt-me">Adoptez-moi</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">A propos</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/associations/create">Espace associations</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className={styles.logo}>
            Les <span>Z</span>animalistes
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>Visiter le site</li>
            <li>A propos</li>
          </ul>
          <div className={styles.socials}>
            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/louis-lecouturier-21b90b204/"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              <Web />
            </a>
            <a
              href="https://www.facebook.com/Leszanimalistes"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              <Facebook />
            </a>
            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/louis-lecouturier-21b90b204/"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noreferrer"
            >
              <Instagram />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <div className={styles.credits}>
        <span>Les Zanimalistes - tous droits réservés</span>
        <span className={styles.separator}></span>
        <span>
          Site codé par{" "}
          <a
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/louis-lecouturier-21b90b204/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noreferrer"
          >
            Louis Lecouturier
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

And it's CSS sheet (the properties that aren't applying in build) :

```
.footerContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

It looks like there are no CSS properties applied to my div in chrome dev tools but when I check the class name, it does have properties assigned to it in my compiled CSS file.

I am using CSS modules and I am not using any CSS frameworks.

Does anybody know how can I solve this problem ?

Thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without more detail. The best we can offer right now is guesses, which is a bit of a waste of everyone's time. Can you include the relevant part of the build configuration? and maybe the relevant CSS?

Comment: @DBS I edited my question, I'm sorry I'm a beginner at React and it's the first time that I "build" a project and I haven't seen any solutions to my problem anywhere...
What do you mean by "build configuration" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution !

for some unknown reason, webpack was adding ";" before some class names in my minified built CSS.

I solved the problem by simply deleting these extra ";" and now everything works as expected

Comment: Nice. I had the same issue making a custom style for `sweetalert`. I just made everything with `!important` and works but next time i'll check if it has the same problem that you had.

Comment: I have wrong ; and I tried !important on every attribute and that did not work

Answer (score 1):

In my case the html file had errors:

```
<meta content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1;maximum-scale=1;user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
```

The meta tag should be this.

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0; name=viewport" />
```

This solved for me the problem